# Android: Need Advice on SQLite, searching slow

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, search, optimization

I have to search a database that is 26024 entries and counting.  It used to be fast with less records but now is taking like 10 seconds and slowing the app. I was wondering if i could get advice as to how speed up the process or if i'm doing anything wrong.  Here is the code.

```
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                 String word = cursor.getString(0);
                 if (word.equals(input)) {
                       String nikus = cursor.getString(1);
                               String def = cursor.getString(2);
                   ret.append(" " + nikus + "\n"+ def + "\n");
                   g = null;
            }
```

EDIT:
In my Database i have a definitions table and in the table there are 3 fields one is the words to be compared to, the sencond is the full word, and the third is the definition itself. Hopefully that helps you guys a little more.

```
    CREATE TABLE [definitions] (
  [word] TEXT, 
  [fullword] TEXT, 
  [definition] TEXT);
```

EDIT: here is the error im getting
01-04 00:47:54.678: E/CursorWindow(4722): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 17, freeSpace() = 13, numRows = 15340

Comment: You can put this method into another thread.

Comment: Put code describe above into run() and then call start().

Comment: how is that going to speed up the search process if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Looks like you're doing a full table scan, going through every entry in the table. You should be pushing processing down to the sqlite engine level from your app. Post your database schema and query so we can help you make them perform better.

Comment: You're searching by just iterating through every record in the database?

Comment: yes since the db wasnt made alphabetically!

Comment: @Freddy I suggest you do some light reading on database basics.  I'm not saying that to be insulting, but your comment on the db not being alphabetical shows a real lack of understanding on how relational databases work.  Unless you add indexes, as far as the database is concerned, your data is always unordered, regardless of whether it was alphabetical when you inserted the data.

Comment: Well I did add indexes but they didn't speed up the process

Comment: @Freddy Indexes will speed up the process only if you're using a where clause.  If you're doing a full table scan like in your code above, the indexes won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

laalto's comment above is correct.  You should be running a select with a where clause that only pulls back the rows where word is equal to input (don't forget about case sensitivity.) An index on the word column will help the query go even faster.

Comment: What if there is more thaqn one word?

Comment: @Freddy You can use an IN clause.  i.e WHERE [word] IN (input1, input2, input3, etc...)